# Compiling a software with GTK which has no configuration script

Tags: debian, gcc, gtk

I bumped into [green](https://github.com/schandinat/green), a PDF viewer for the Framebuffer. I would like to compile it, but I am not having much success, although I have installed all the dependencies...

The error I am getting is:

```
$/home/Data/Software/green-0.2$ make
cc -D GREEN_SYSCONFIG_FILE=\"/usr/local/etc/green.conf\" -D GREEN_USERCONFIG_FILE=\".green.conf\" -Os -Wall -c main.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags) -o main.o
cc -Os -Wall -c green.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags) -o green.o
cc -Os -Wall -c sdl.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags) $(sdl-config --cflags) -o sdl.o
sdl.c: In function ‘GetInput’:
sdl.c:91:3: warning: case value ‘37’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c:85:3: warning: case value ‘123’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c:86:3: warning: case value ‘125’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c:94:3: warning: case value ‘126’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c:90:3: warning: case value ‘4294967207’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c: In function ‘RenderPage’:
sdl.c:120:2: error: unknown type name ‘GdkPixbuf’
sdl.c:120:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gdk_pixbuf_new’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
sdl.c:120:34: error: ‘GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sdl.c:120:34: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
sdl.c:136:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_page_render_to_pixbuf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
sdl.c:137:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
sdl.c:137:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
sdl.c:138:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
sdl.c:139:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
sdl.c: In function ‘Green_SDL_Main’:
sdl.c:402:21: warning: variable ‘left_y’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
sdl.c:402:9: warning: variable ‘left_x’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
make: *** [sdl.o] Error 1
$:/home/Data/Software/green-0.2$
```

Obviously he can't find GdkPixbuf, but this construct is defined in:

```
# ls /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h 
/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h
```

When I add to the file sdl.c the following line:

```
#include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>
```

I am "greeted" with following error:

```
# make
cc -Os -Wall -c sdl.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags) $(sdl-config --cflags) -o sdl.o
sdl.c:20:35: fatal error: gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [sdl.o] Error 1
```

My question is then, how do I "convince" gcc to compile this code?

Thanks in advance, 
Oz

UPDATE:
adding the full path to gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h yields:

```
ozdeb@yenitiny:/home/Data/Software/green-0.2$ make
cc -D GREEN_SYSCONFIG_FILE=\"/usr/local/etc/green.conf\" -D GREEN_USERCONFIG_FILE=\".green.conf\" -Os -Wall -c main.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags) -o main.o
cc -Os -Wall -c green.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags) -o green.o
cc -Os -Wall -c sdl.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags) $(sdl-config --cflags) -o sdl.o
sdl.c:21:63: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]
sdl.c:21:63: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive [enabled by default]
In file included from sdl.c:21:0:
/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h:32:44: fatal error: gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-features.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [sdl.o] Error 1
```

Comment: `/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h` isn't the same as `[/usr/include/]gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h`

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, then? is gdk-pixbuf depreciated? I could not find anywhere a package containing it, besides that. Plus, adding the full path, still does not compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of an answer, not really fully compiling, but I managed to solve the part where sdl.c fails to compile with:

```
cc -c sdl.c `sdl-config --cflags` `pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags` `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags` -o sdl.o
```

Comment: What error are you facing while compiling with the above mentioned command? By the way, gdk-pixbuf-2.0 is the package whose CFLAGS you might be looking for. It should be part of [libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gdk-pixbuf2.0-dev) but once you include `gtk+-2.0` that should have been included implicitly. Can you check what `gtk+-2.0` pkg-config dependencies are `pkg-config --print-requires gtk+-2.0`? gdk-pixbuf-2.0 should have been part of it. FYI on Linux Mint 12 gdk-pixbuf is a dependency of poppler-glib as well, so the code compiles without issues